# printing with ostream and print functio, with inner function

Tags: c++11

i want to print the polynom. i dont know already if its a syntax problem or that i just dont understand something

```
class polynom : public func {
  public:
  polynom(const int order, int* ptr_array); 
  polynom(const polynom& polynom_); 
  void printcoefs(ostream&)  const ;
  friend polynom operator+(polynom const &, polynom const &) ;
  friend polynom operator-(polynom const &, polynom const &);
  friend polynom operator*(polynom const &, polynom const &);
  polynom operator=(polynom const & poly) { //assignment operator
      int* ptr = new int[poly.n_ + 1];
      for (int i = 0; i < poly.n_ + 1; i++)
          ptr[i] = poly.coefs_[i];
      return polynom(poly.n_, ptr);
      }
  polynom Derivative();
  polynom Integral();
  int funcout(const int& x) const;
  friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& out, const polynom& polynom_);
  ~polynom();
  void Print(ostream& out) const;

protected:
  int n_; //order of the polynom
  int* coefs_; //coefficients 
};
```

this is what i wrote for the pritning functions

```
  void polynom::Print(ostream &out) const {
     printcoefs(cout);
     cout << endl;
     cout << "Derivative: ";
     polynom der=this->Derivative;  <-error here
     der.printcoefs(cout);
     cout << endl;
     polynom inte =this->Integral;
     cout << "Integral: ";
     inte.printcoefs(cout);
     cout << endl;
  }
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const polynom & polynom_)
 {
    polynom_.Print(out);
     return out;
 }
```

it gives me either 
Error   C3867   'polynom::Derivative': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member , if i write it like this.
Error   C2276   '*': illegal operation on bound member function expression  ,if i try to use "this" as a pointer.
any help will be appreciated

Comment: `Derivative` is a function, you probably want `polynom der=this->Derivative();` Same with `Integral`. You might also consider actually using the stream passed into your print function instead of hardcoded `cout`.

Comment: if i write it like this i get: cont polynom * const. the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function polynom::Derivative

Comment: @RetiredNinja can you please explain the second part of your answer? about using the stream?

Comment: You can't call a non-const function from a const function. Perhaps `Derivative()` should be const too. For the stream, you pass a stream named `out` to your function, but all of your code uses `cout` instead.